# Install Lubuntu 12.04 from Windows XP

Tags: lubuntu, wubi, reboot

I want to install Lubuntu 12.04 (my PC don't support more) from Windows XP without reboot system. How I can do this? I heard something about wubi, but I am not sure from whre to download it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it without rebooting, as you have to boot into the live CD / USB, and then into the OS when complete.

Also, you probably want 14.04, it is the latest version (and in my opinion, it runs much faster).

First download the [lubuntu iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) and also [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), then use unetbootin to install it on a disk / USB / SD card.

Once complete, restart the computer with the USB in, and from the BIOS (F2 / Del / F12) choose removable media or similar.

As it is booting, choose install or try (double click on the desktop icon to install from the live version) and follow the simple instructions.

Comment: i don't have usb or cd yet, this is why i want to install without reboot. do you know anything about wubi?

Comment: You could partition your harddrive, (so you have about 8GB on one partition), then use unetbootin to install it on there, and finally boot from there, via the BIOS, instead of the removeable media. Then use the install wizard to install it on the big partition. look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Installation for info on wubi.

Comment: Lubuntu 12.04 has reached its End Of Life and is no longer supported.  Ubuntu 12.04 is still supported or you could install Lubuntu 14.04 which is the latest version.

Comment: @Rex added to post, I hadn't read that part of question, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Also, I believe that Wubi install has been discontinued so that option is not open to you.

Comment: Wubi has some [limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29#Limitations)...

Comment: @Rex I don't think it has been discontinued, but it still doesn't support W8 so it isn't especially up to date! I hadn't heard of it before, but at first glance, it seems quite a long way of doing the same thing...

Comment: @Rex my computer doesn't support Lubuntu 14.04, I tried to test it in ViruaLBox

Comment: @User3144605 how much ram do you have? And what is the intel?

Comment: i have 1 GB ram and AMD Sempron 2400+

Comment: Who told you it was unsupported? My computer has 1GB and an Intel celeron, and it works! It may be unsupported, but I think it will still work for you.

Comment: i get an error: I don't have PAE support ,  or something like this.

Comment: @user3144605 Ahh OK. Does 12.04 work without that though?

Comment: I know 12.04 don't need PAE. I have 1 GB RAM ,CPU AMD Sempron 2400+ , GPU RADEON 9250 and 80 GB HDD. Do you think Lubuntu 12.04 will work good?

Comment: You can use forcepae in 14.04.  When the menu comes up, choose F6 Other Options.